# Angular 2 passes array to ngFor and each element is the whole array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I'm trying to use a ngFor in a nested element this way, with the `@Input()` decorator:

```
<app-sever-element *ngFor="let server_element of serverElements" 
                   [element]="serverElements">
</app-sever-element>
```

Inside the component of app-sever-element, this is what I have:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">{{ element.name }}</div>
    <p>
        {{ element.content }}
    </p>
</div>
```

This is the array I'm accessing to with a custom property, declared in the AppComponent

```
serverElements=[
   { type: 'server', name: 'Test', content: 'This is only a test' }
];
```

However, I'm getting an [empty element](http://prntscr.com/i385ok) and when I try to dig into the element with the filter json `{{element | json}}`, the [whole array](http://prntscr.com/i386ii) is passed as the element in each iteration

I really can't tell what's going on and why the whole array is passed as an element in the for loop, I have already tried with multiple objects in the array and the element is always the whole array

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[element]="server_element"`?

Comment: @yurzui I'm a dumb and you are absolutely right, can you answer the question to give you the credit you deserve!

Comment: Voted to close as the error was caused by a typo

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing you the whole array serverElements if I am not mistaken. Hope you were trying to pass server_element as input.